# шаблон в angular

Tags: html, angularjs

Есть кусок *HTML* кода, который часто повторяется. В нем нет ни какой логики. Просто элемент верстки. Есть ли способ в *AngularJS* вынести этот кусок в отдельный *.html* файл и вставлять в код, не используя директиву?

Comment: почему _не используя директиву_? `ng-include` стандартная директива как раз и вставляет указанную разметку.

Comment: Я имел в виду: _не писать свою директиву_.

Comment: тогда _ng-include_ - то что вам нужно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для вставки разметки из файлов или шаблонов можно использовать встроенную директиву [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

```
ng-include="'путь к файлу или id шаблона'"
```

Comment: Благодарю всех, кто откликнулся! Это именно то, что мне было нужно.